# How to parse [object object] array in jquery

Tags: jquery

Getting [Object, Object] as the result from controller.How can I get each value of ID and title in  `$.each(data, function (index, el) {}`

```
[Object, Object]

0:Object
ID: 9
title: "15Sep2015"

1: Object
ID: 15
title: "rrr"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
$.each(data, function (index, el) {
   var id = el.ID , // or el['ID']
       title = el.title ; // or el['title'] 
});
```

Ref : **[Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)**